# RDP into computer which is VPN connected to another network

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

I have been able to successfully RDP into a work machine in the following manner:

- My home machine is connected to the work machine via a FortiClient VPN connection.  I then use windows RDP to connect to the work machine "X.Y.local".

However, while I am remotely connected into the work machine, if I then connect the work machine to a vpn to a different network, it drops the RDP connection.

Is there a way for me to remote into a machine that is connected via vpn to a different network B?

So far, I have tried connecting to B then attempting to remote into my work machine which has been unsuccessful.

Comment: While connected to the VPN on the work machine, can you access from the work machine other computers/devices on its local network? Did you try other VPNs?

Comment: As in my question, as soon as I connect to the vpn on my work machine (via RDP), it drops my connection.  So currently, I can't RDP into the work machine.

Comment: Disconnect the VPN session from the Fortinet VPN management server. It sounds like the network cannot route which it's connected based on the IP subnet and such it gets when connected to the VPN. Are you the network admin or have access to the network gear at the work location? If not, I'd start by asking them why it cannot route or be accessed when connected to that particular VPN client connection. I've seen similar things like this on different networks where it works on one network but not on the other with the same VPN connection on both.

Comment: My question was different, intending to see if the VPN is compulsory in nature, and without using RDP.